# Why use Python format rather than slicing?

Tags: python, format, slice

I've inherited some Python code and during a review I discovered several instances in which the author uses `format` to slice strings, such as:

```
someStr = 'ABCDEFG'
newStr1 = '{0}{1}{2}'.format(someStr[0], someStr[1], someStr[2])
```

Why would they do that, instead of slicing it, such as:

```
newStr2 = someStr[0:3]
```

Both achieve the same result, even when using a left-padded numeric sequence such as '012345' (meaning that '012' is produced, as expected, rather than '12').

It seems to me that slicing is more intuitive, so I'm curious if there is an advantage to using `format`?

Comment: That does seem odd, but maybe they simply weren't aware of slicing (note that the leading `0` is the default and therefore optional)? Fundamentally, you'd have to ask the author.

Comment: The 2nd method seems much more preferable.  The only reason I can think to use the first would be if you weren't sure if the original string had all 3 characters.  Slicing `'AB'[0:3]` will result in `'AB'` but the `.format()` route would throw an error.

Comment: @Jkdc that is a good point, slices are forgiving but indexing isn't.

Comment: @Jkdc: There are better ways to ensure that there is a minimal length. Even so, I'd have added a comment to the code at that point to explain that I was using `str.format()` for that side-effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not advantage to using `str.format()` here, I have no idea why they are doing that. There is a small chance they were doing this to force an indexing error if the inputstring was shorter than 3 characters, but I'd have expected an explicit comment stating this (and personally I'd have made that an explicit check).

Just use a slice:

```
newStr2 = somStr[:3]
```

Note that you can drop the `0` here; it is the default. If you are going to update the code (do so only when doing other maintenance), you might want to update it to using the [PEP-8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), including naming conventions. Local variables should use `lower_case_with_underscores`, not `mixedCamelCase`.

Comment: The input string is explicitly checked for sufficient length immediately prior to the code in question. So it would seem there is no advantage in this case.